# Sync test MySQL database with production (both online)

Tags: mysql, heroku, vpn, data-synchronization

Is there a convenient way of syncing changes between two MySQL databases, each running on its separate server?

I  have a development / testing db on Heroku's JawsDB and would like to update changes (mostly structural changes) directly to my production db on my vps.

Comment: Perhaps I've missed something, but is that a good idea? Surely you want to do some testing first to verify that the changes are correct? That's the whole point of a test system, normally. If you just sync immediately then you might as well apply the changes directly to the production server, there's basically no difference, if you aren't going to check them.  But anyway I'm not sure there's any existing process to synchronise schema changes (probably because, as I've just described, it doesn't sound like a brilliant idea).

Comment: Or do really mean you just want a way to do a automatic schema compare (and then have it generate the necessary change scripts) as and when the time is right?

Comment: If you haven't kept track of what has been changed and signed off in test would this really be a good idea?

Comment: "mostly structural changes"—this is exactly what database migrations are for. Are you using migrations? What programming language and, if applicable, framework are you using? There's a good chance migrations are built in, or easily available via a dependency.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I want to test and later "commit" changes to the production database when ready to push changes instead of exporting the dump and importing again.

Comment: @P.Salmon the test database would be the exact version - copy of existing production database. I'd test for any errors there and push updated structure when ready. Something like git for database :)

Comment: @Chris Im using PHP and havent tried migrations yet. Will check it out.

Comment: Here's some [possibly useful documentation from the Laravel framework](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations). Even if you're not using that particular framework you should be able to get some useful background from that documentation. Other frameworks provide other, similar tools. There are also standalone products like Liquibase or Flyway that might be good options. [Wikipedia may also be helpful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration). Good luck!